# how to stop apache2, mysql from starting automatically as computer starts?

Tags: 11.04, server, startup, apache2, mysql

My os is 11.04.

I have `apache2` & `mysql` installed.

How to stop apache2, mysql from starting automatically as computer starts?

Answer (score 51, accepted):

MySQL is handled by upstart. In 11.04 you can use the new override feature to modify the starting behaviour:

```
echo "manual" >> /etc/init/mysql.override
```

See [the section "Disabling a Job from Automatically Starting" in the Upstart Cookbook](http://upstart.ubuntu.com/cookbook/#disabling-a-job-from-automatically-starting)

Apache still uses traditional SysV init scripts so you use

```
 update-rc.d -f apache2 remove
```

to remove the links from `/etc/rcX.d` or, alternatively, use

```
 update-rc.d apache2 disable
```

which "disables" the script by changing it from a start script `S91apache2` to a stop script `K09apache2`. This is reversible by `update-rc.d apache2 enable`.

Comment: Apache doesn't use upstart.

Comment: Yes, my error - I converted it to use Upstart on my system...

Comment: Got this error "bash: /etc/init/mysql.override: Permission denied" in both case

Comment: @Florian: How did you convert? and whats the advantage of converting?

Comment: @Rahul: You get the error as both the echo and the update-rc.d need to be run with sudo.

Comment: $ sudo echo "manual" >> /etc/init/mysql.override

Comment: Got error "bash: /etc/init/mysql.override: Permission denied"

Comment: @RAHUL It can't work becouse redirection is created by bash *before* executing `sudo` - and that why the file is created as your user, not as a root. You can use such command: `sudo su -c 'echo "manual" >> /etc/init/mysql.override'`.

Comment: @Rahul: To convert it you have to write a .conf file for upstart. I just did it to learn how it is done.

Comment: @FlorianDiesch Will that work for 11.10 as well?

Comment: @radek: Yes. That should work with any Ubuntu version that uses Upstart 1.3 or later.

Comment: I am using [mariadb](http://downloads.mariadb.org/mariadb/repositories/) flavor of Mysql and found that it was still managed by sysvinit rather than Upstart. Removed it from startup by executing ```sudo update-rc.d -f mysql remove``` .

Comment: @RahulPrasad @LukaszStelmach - this is a common pattern, but I hate `sudo su -c 'quoted commands'`, you can just use `tee`, like in `echo "manual" | sudo tee -a /etc/init/mysql.override`. For `>` use just `tee`, for `>>` it's `tee -a`.

Answer (score 15):

Interestingly, it's a different answer for each package in 11.04.

- apache2 uses System V style init scripts.  To disable it from boot: 
  `sudo update-rc.d -f apache2 remove`
- However, mysql uses an Upstart job, to disable it, create an "override" file:
   `echo "manual" | sudo tee /etc/init/mysql.override`

To learn more about override files, see: [The Upstart Cookbook](http://upstart.ubuntu.com/cookbook/#ubuntu-natty-override-files-ubuntu-transient)

Answer (score 3):

This thread will help you: https://superuser.com/questions/35151/how-do-i-stop-services-from-starting-on-boot-on-ubuntu

Comment: This only works for services using SysV style init scripts. Ubuntu is switching to Upstart for most services so update-rc.d doesn't work anymore.

Answer (score 1):

[update-rc.d](http://www.debuntu.org/how-to-manage-services-with-update-rc.d) is a good CLI tool to do this. The linked page has an example involving apache2

Answer (score 1):

It was't working for me. When trying to disable mysql in ubuntu I was receiving the message:

*System start/stop links for /etc/init.d/mysql do not exist.*

So I found a work around in this link: http://forum.linode.com/viewtopic.php?t=5594

> sudo mkdir /etc/init.disabled
>
> sudo mv /etc/init/mysql.conf /etc/init.disabled/

And that's it.

Answer (score 1):

With heavy adoption of `systemd` as system manager and init system for debian based distributions like ubuntu , we can now use `systemctl` commands to prevent a service from automatically starting at boot.

for example :

> sudo systemctl disable apache2

To start using it when required , you can use:

> sudo systemctl start apache2

To stop using it, you can use:

> sudo systemctl stop apache2

And to see if it's running or not , you can use :

> sudo systemctl status apache2

Answer (score 0):

use rcconf to enable/disable a service to auto run on boot.

`sudo apt-get install rcconf`

Now, type `sudo rcconf`

And you will see list of services that are installed on your Ubuntu machine. Those marked with star are auto run during boot process. To disable Apache, MySql just navigate to it using arrows and press space bar. Then navigate to OK button using Tab key and again press Space to save configuration.