# How to stop mysql from running at boot time?

Tags: boot, mysql

Currently, my MySQL server starts on every server boot. For a couple reasons, this is undesirable behavior. Is there a way to disable this behavior?

Answer (score 138, accepted):

Since 15.04 you can simply do:

```
sudo systemctl disable mysql
```

Comment: Indeed.  For 15.04, this is the answer you seek.

Comment: Awesome, finally I found a solution for this! The other methods don't work to me.

Comment: I can't start it again, how do I start mysql after the command?

Comment: @rneves did you try `enable` or `reenable`?

Comment: @thebugfinder I've tried `enable`, I don't know about `reenable`, but `enable` forces me restart the computer to start mysql again

Comment: @rneves then after `enable` you should run `sudo systemctl start mysql`

Comment: Didn't work for me .. I had `insserv: warning: current start runlevel(s) (empty) of script 'mysql' overrides LSB defaults (2 3 4 5).`

Comment: BTW, `sudo systemctl is-enabled mysql` help to check whether enabled currently.

Comment: If you're using MariaDB, use `sudo systemctl disable mariadb`.

Comment: I confirm it works in Ubuntu **18.04** too

Answer (score 86):

To prevent mysql from starting on boot:

1. Open the terminal: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>
2. Open the `mysql.conf` file: `nano /etc/init/mysql.conf`
3. Comment out the `start on` line near the top of the file, the `start on` might be spread across two lines, so comment out both. (comment adding `#` at the beginning)

If you want to manually start mysql, use the following command:

```
service mysql start
```

---

Taken liberally from [here.](https://superuser.com/questions/138116/disable-mysql-startup-in-ubuntu-10-04)

Comment: This is a very usefull answer for more than one initiation at start up.

Comment: Tried, I have ``/usr/sbin/mysqld`` and ``/bin/sh /usr/bin/mysqld_safe`` running. Commented out everything but didn't helped.

Comment: IMO this is the best answer.

Comment: in Linux Mint 18.2 Cinnamon I removed /etc/init/mysql.conf with no change.  Mysql server still running on startup.  @thebugfinder solution worked for me

Comment: anacron.conf and whoopsie.conf is all i can see in /etc/init @maniat1k

Answer (score 16):

In Ubuntu 18.04, `sudo systemctl disable mysql` will prevent `mysql-server` from autostarting on boot.

For linux, there are 3 main init systems: `Systemd`, `Upstart` and `SysV`. Although nearly all Linux systems run on Systemd. The other two init systems might also co-exist in your system.

For `Systemd`, use command `sudo systemctl disable mysql`;
For `Upstart`, use `echo manual >> /etc/init/mysql.override`;
For `SysV`, run the following command `sudo update-rc.d mysql disable`

If you'd like to find which init system is running on your server, please read this [answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/196183/340999).

Comment: Also worked for me on Ubuntu 20.04, thanks!

Answer (score 9):

Things have changed quite a bit in Ubuntu now. I think from version 11 onwards.
MySQL is handled by **Upstart** while Apache still uses traditional **SysV init** scripts

For MySQL, you can use the new override feature in **Upstart** to modify the starting behaviour:

```
sudo echo "manual" >> /etc/init/mysql.override
```

For more info, see the section "[Disabling a Job from Automatically Starting](http://upstart.ubuntu.com/cookbook/#disabling-a-job-from-automatically-starting)" in the Upstart Cookbook.

As Apache still uses the traditional **SysV init** scripts you can use

```
sudo update-rc.d -f apache2 remove
```

to remove the links from `/etc/rcX.d` or, alternatively use

```
sudo update-rc.d apache2 disable
```

which "disables" the script by changing it from a start script to a stop script. This is reversible by

```
sudo update-rc.d apache2 enable
```

---

*Most of this information I got from here: https://askubuntu.com/a/40077/24678*

Comment: If you want to restore the service `sudo update-rc.d apache2 defaults`

Answer (score 6):

There are two Guis I can think of. From Applications -> Ubuntu Software Center search for "boot up manager". After installing you will find it in the System -> Administration -> BootUP-Manager. Another is Webmin. Webmin uses your browser. After installing point your browser to https://localhost:10000/ Look for services and work it from there.

Comment: This method didn't work for me on 16.04

Answer (score 5):

Well I am using Ubuntu 20.04 on my laptop. The problem I faced is that mysql service starts at boot up and takes 32 seconds to move to the next step in the sequence of bootup. So I decided to disable it from the boot sequence to make it boot faster. For this I followed the below steps:

1. I checked for mysql running status by command:

   sudo service mysql status

The result showed the status as in the snippet shown below. There I noticed the source of it's loading - " loaded (/lib/systemd/system/mysql.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled) "

```
● mysql.service - MySQL Community Server
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/mysql.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: inactive (dead) since Thu 2020-04-16 03:45:09 IST; 26min ago
```

2. So I decided to disabled it using systemctl command as:

   sudo systemctl disable mysql

result of the above command:

```
Synchronizing state of mysql.service with SysV service script with /lib/systemd/systemd-sysv-install.
Executing: /lib/systemd/systemd-sysv-install disable mysql
Removed /etc/systemd/system/multi-user.target.wants/mysql.service.
```

3. Now I can manually start / stop or check the status of mysql service by using the following commands:

   sudo service mysql start

   sudo service mysql stop

   sudo service mysql status

I hope this might help. Cheers.

Comment: duplicate of https://askubuntu.com/a/656474

Answer (score 2):

Or if your really laze like me you could just open a Terminal session and then type:

```
sudo perl -pi.orig -e 's/start\s+on/#start\s+on/' /etc/init/mysql.conf && sudo perl -pi.orig -e 's/and\s+/#and/g' /etc/init/mysql.conf
```

You can then just issue a reboot command then your system will boot-up without mysql started.

Comment: This command could be improved. It is adding a `+` leaving the line like this: `#start+on blahblahblah` but it works!

Answer (score 2):

Actually, there is also another method to accomplish this, via the sysv-rc-conf tool.

You can install it by typing

```
sudo apt-get install sysv-rc-conf
```

It allows you to take control over all available services, including running/stopping them in place and configuring services' operation per runlevel.

Edit: You have to run tis tool as root:

```
sudo sysv-rc-conf
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`chkconfig`](https://packages.debian.org/en/wheezy/chkconfig) tool package

```
$ chkconfig --level 345 mysqld off
```

Comment: Please elaborate your answer. Why do you think this solves the question? You could e.g. add a link to a manual as reference.