# What makes mysql service autostart, while it's disabled in BootUp-manager?

Tags: boot, mysql, services

The `mysql` service is not enabled in `BootUp-manager`, yet it is working after system starts. Is it awaken by another service? How to determine what causes that?

**EDIT**

Fix as instructed [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/57381/how-to-stop-mysql-from-running-at-boot-time/57382#57382).

Comment: What is BootUp-manager? What version of Ubuntu are you using? Have you used [this procedure](http://askubuntu.com/a/57382/62483)?

Comment: Package `bum` - BootUp-manager provides graphical services on/off and autostart managing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AFAIK MySQL differs from other services. For instance:

```
sudo update-rc.d nginx disable # Works
sudo update-rc.d mysql disable # Does not
```

I don't know how BootUp Manager (`bum`) works, but it wouldn't surprise me that it is not capable to manage MySQL.

To disable MySQL from startup you will have to *manually* do it, for that see: [How to stop mysql from running at boot time?](https://askubuntu.com/q/57381/62483)

Again, no sure if this is a bug on that tool or not (no sources for say so).