# "Failed to spawn mysql main process: unable to execute: No such file or directory"

Tags: upgrade, mysql

I'm a newbie on MySQL ground so bear with me.

I've just finished upgrading 11.10 to 12.04.

Everything seemed to work without any hiccups and all my software and settings are working fine. Apart from MySQL.

When I try:

```
sudo start mysql
```

I receive an error:

```
start: Job failed to start
```

Where can I possibly diagnose what the problem is? And (hopefully) - how to sort it out?

(I disabled automatic start following advice [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/40072/how-to-stop-apache2-mysql-from-starting-automatically-as-computer-starts) if that is of some importance)

---

Update 1:

Both outputs of:

```
cat /var/log/mysql.err 
cat /var/log/mysql.log
```

are empty.

Output of `dmesg | grep mysql`:

```
[ 1401.785141] type=1400 audit(1335619832.181:25): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_replace" name="/usr/sbin/mysqld" pid=16165 comm="apparmor_parser"
[ 1401.791089] init: Failed to spawn mysql main process: unable to execute: No such file or directory
```

---

Update 2:

As indicated by AWinter below - it seemed that MySQL disappeared automagically after upgrade and had to be reinstalled.

Answer (score 49, accepted):

Check that mysql-server-5.1 package was uninstalled, seems it might persist after upgrade.  I had the same error and had to purge MySQL server 5.1 and 5.5 then re-install.

First make a backup of your /var/lib/mysql/ directory just to be safe.

```
sudo cp -R /var/lib/mysql/ ~/mysql
```

Next purge MySQL (this will remove php5-mysql and phpmyadmin as well as a number of other libraries so be prepared to re-install some items after this.

```
sudo apt-get purge mysql-server-5.1 mysql-common
```

Remove the folder /etc/mysql/ and it's contents

```
sudo rm /etc/mysql/ -R
```

Next check that your old database files are still in /var/lib/mysql/ if they are not then copy them back in to the folder then chown root:root

(only run these if the files are no longer there)

```
sudo mkdir /var/lib/mysql/
sudo chown root:root /var/lib/mysql/ -R
sudo cd ~/mysql/
sudo cp * /var/lib/mysql/ -R
```

Next install mysql server

```
sudo apt-get install mysql-server
```

Finally re-install any missing packages like phpmyadmin and php5-mysql.

Comment: Excellent. Worked as a charm. All working again. One note: I did not have to remove this directory `sudo rm /etc/mysql/ -R` - it was simply not present in my case. Anyway - luckily it was just a local install to test Wordpress.. Wonder what would happen on a real server o_O

Comment: apt-get --reinstall install mysql-server-x.x did the job for me.

Comment: This worked for me, but I should probably have done an `apt-get update` before hand, because it removed dovecot and php5-mysql. I could only reinstall these after the update. Once I had done, everything was once again working fine.

Comment: I get `-bash: cd: /var/lib/mysql/: Permission denied` and using `sudo -i` doesn't even work.

Comment: @LittleBigBot I made a change that should fix that.

Comment: Upgrading from 5.5 to 5.6 using MySQL's add-apt tool. All I had to do was `sudo apt-get purge mysql-server-5.5`, and then `sudo apt-get install mysql-server`. I didn't lose any databases either! Yay!

Answer (score 15):

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure mysql-server-5.5
```

Comment: Not a very friendly answer, but it worked for me :-)

Comment: Did not work for me :[

Answer (score 12):

I had this same issue and for me it was the InnoDB logfiles were a different size than mysql was expecting, and failed silently during upgrade.

I had a custom configuration file that was wiped out on the upgrade to 12.04 that set the log file sizes to something other than what the default configuration.

You have to remove the files: /var/lib/mysql/ib_logfile*

After the files are gone, mysql can now start and create fresh log files of the default size.

Comment: Bingo. In our case a dev had altered some config settings for innodb (and neither he nor I knew that that could cause an issue). This prevented mysql from starting. Deleting those config files allowed MySQL to start.

Comment: Bingo - changed the config setting for innodb_log_file_size.

Answer (score 10):

Most errors will show up by starting the server in verbose non-daemon mode and watching the output:

```
sudo mysqld --verbose
```

Answer (score 7):

I had the same problem, but none of the answers above helped me. So as a final hope I tried to free some disk space. I simply remove unnecessary log files from /var/log which freed some 2.5G space. Then MySQL started normally.

Comment: Yep, this was my problem as well. mysql was not starting during bootup, as it had been. Later was the System info that renders to the terminal; "Usage of /: 95.1%" So, there wasn't enough free space for mysql (and other processes) to start. I needed to do some file cleanup, and mysql started without a problem.

Comment: This was my case. Disc cleanup and Mysql start working.

Answer (score 5):

This sometimes happens and although there are a couple of different problems that could make mysql not start I will write here some of the most common ones that I know of:

NOTE - Because explaining most common problems I am assuming that you have already tried removing and installing, or simply reinstalling the mysql service as so:

To Install - `sudo apt-get install mysql-server mysql-client`
To Remove - `sudo apt-get remove mysql-server mysql-client`
To Purge (Remove files + Config) - `sudo apt-get purge mysql-server mysql-client`
To Reinstall - `sudo apt-get install --reinstall mysql-server mysql-client`

1. `my.cnf`file is not in the default directory. It should be (By default) be located in either `/etc/my.cnf` or `/etc/mysql/my.cnf`.
2. Not enough space in the hard drive where the mysql data files are located. If the Databases get too big and take 100% of the hard drive, the service will fail.
3. After upgrade check that the `my.cnf` file is in the correct place. Depending on how you upgraded or from what version you upgraded from, it could be in `/etc/my.cnf` or `/etc/mysql/my.cnf` as mentioned before. Also remember that the file can also be named `mysql.conf` and not just `my.cnf`. This happens in cases where you have downloaded the binary from **mysql.com**.
4. Doing a `dmesg` to see what the mysql service is is throwing as an error message helps since it gives the loading error. It might also say why this is happening. If you type `dmesg` alone in the terminal it will show you the world. What we want is the info about mysql so do something like this: `dmesg | grep mysql` this will throw you any lines that contain mysql in them.
5. Check that the `my.cnf` or `mysql.conf` file is correct. In 12.04 MySQL is version 5.5, in 11.10 it is version 5.1. It might have some changes in the conf file (Haven't actually checked that) and it might sound silly but it sure can give you some trouble.
6. Errors related to **socket problems** normally are the fault of the `my.cnf` or `mysql.conf` file pointing to the wrong place, they error will normally show as:

   > Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock'

   The other source of this problem is related to the `mysql` file in `/etc/init.d` that it is pointing at the wrong folder because it might be using an older script than the one needed for the actual mysql on the system (It might not have updated correctly, did not overwrite the config file, etc..). So just edit any of this two files and see if they are pointing somewhere else and then simply do a `sudo service mysql restart` to check if it works.
7. To have a better look at the error specific outputs of mysql do the following:

   `cat /var/log/mysql.err` - Will show you the mysql errors. I would make it like this `cat /var/log/mysql.err | less` if you happen to see too much information fly by since `less` will help you scroll your way through the output of `cat`.

   Same goes for `cat /var/log/mysql.log` If you see the error there maybe putting it in the question or as a comment will help answer this faster.
8. If you are suffering from connection problems and the service it is actually running, try to see if the Firewall of the server is allowing connections through the 3306 port (Incoming connections). Afterwards check if the router (If it applies) has not blocked port 3306. Basically do a network test to see where the problem related to the port assigned to mysql is originated from.

If all is good, to test if the mysql service is running type `service mysql status`

As a last resort. If you happen to be running mysql but you can not login try the following:

1. Stop the MySQL Server:

   `sudo /etc/init.d/mysql stop` or `sudo service mysql stop`
2. Start the `mysqld` service manually with manual configuration

   `sudo mysqld --skip-grant-tables &`

   (Remember to add the & else you will have to open another terminal. The & sends the process to the background and you can kill on using the same terminal).
3. Login to the mysql database as **ROOT**

   `mysql -u root mysql`
4. Type the following replacing the **MyPASSWORD** with your new password

   `UPDATE user SET Password=PASSWORD('MyPASSWORD') WHERE User='root';`
   `FLUSH PRIVILEGES;`
   `EXIT;`

This should be enought to login to your Mysql service as root again. Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks for prompt feedback. my.cnf file is in `/etc/mysql/my.cnf` in my case. Is that correct location? `dmesg` gives me pleeenty of output which is beyond my comprehension :/ I indeed had 5.1 installed - does that have any consequences?

Comment: Don't worry about the location if you do find the file. Let me update the answer to provide a better look at the mysql output in dmesg.

Answer (score 4):

I had the same problem after upgrading to Ubuntu Server 12.04 LTS, running

```
sudo apt-get install mysql-server
```

was enough to fix it, although it complained about an old database of spotweb. I fixed that by removing spotweb:

```
sudo apt-get purge spotweb
```

and reconfiguring mysql:

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure mysql-server-5.5
```

Answer (score 4):

I will add this incase someone faces similar issues. I tried all the uninstalling and re-installing to no avail.
The key to finding the solution was that upstart places it's error logs in this folder

**/var/log/upstart/**

for mysql

**/var/log/upstart/mysql.log**

when I opened it had this message

> AppArmor parser error for /etc/apparmor.d/usr.sbin.mysqld in
> /etc/apparmor.d/tunables/global at line 15: Could not open
> 'tunables/home'

When I looked in the **/etc/apparmor.d/tunables/** folder
I was missing the home file in that so I created one

gedit /etc/apparmor.d/tunables/home
and copied the contents from another computer
which had these non commented lines

> @{HOME}=@{HOMEDIRS}/*/ /root/
>
> @{HOMEDIRS}=/home/

someone face a similar issue here

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/mysql-5.5/+bug/982303

then after that I was able to restart the service

Answer (score 2):

In my case it was way easier than some answers here. I found the [related bug on launchpad](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/mysql-5.5/+bug/934013) and the fix was as mentioned there in comment 9:

```
sudo touch /etc/apparmor.d/local/usr.sbin.mysqld
sudo service apparmor restart
```

Answer (score 1):

After upgrading I found that mysql-server/mysql-server-5.5 was not installed and neither 5.1. I renamed my.cnf to my.cnf_old and I tried to install mysql-serven. During installation there was an error message that the root password could not be set. After this I checked my configs, apparmor and so on. All seemed to be ok. My next attempt was to reconfigure mysql-server but it complained that the package was not installed completely. So I decided to uninstall and during this apt-get fixed the package and now it is working. I don't know why because I changed nothing.

Answer (score 1):

I had similar problems, but were quickly tracked down to apparmor, which I remembered had given me this issue previously.

If you make changes to these settings and your system uses apparmor, you may
also need to also adjust /etc/apparmor.d/usr.sbin.mysqld.
Eg. these lines were added (to allow a symlink to the my.cnf, and to allow the symlinked file to be read, presumably):

/usr/sbin/mysqld {
    ...
  /etc/mysql/*.cnf lr,
  /path/to/symlinked/my.cnf r,
    ...
 }

Answer (score 1):

In my case I tried to install MySQL on a fresh installation of Ubuntu 12.04, but I didn't understand why it gave me an error on setting the password for the 'root' user. I tried all the solutions above, but nothing to do.

Then I decided to purge/remove everything, I uninstalled MySQL server and removed all its folders (/etc/mysql/ and /var/lib/mysql/), eventually thank to a sort of randomness it didn't give any error during the reinstallation and I was able to set the password and start the server instance.

Answer (score 0):

In the terminal you can install it again, and makes it run my.cnf you can type:

```
sudo apt-get install mysql-server-5.1
sudo apt-get --reconfigure mysql-server-5.1
sudo apt-get update
sudo start mysql my.cnf
```

it might work this way.

Answer (score 0):

I am having trouble that adding `performance_schema` under `[mysqld]` in `/etc/mysql/my.conf` causes this failure. Removed that line and mysql was able to start again.

Edit:
Turns out One gig of ram is just not enough to start mysqld with performance_schema enabled. I bumped to 3 gigs and it worked fine.