# 12.04 update is stuck on preconfiguring packages

Tags: upgrade, updates, partial-upgrade

For a while I have the problem mentioned in the title. Update is stuck on pre-configuring packages without any other error. I tried almost everything I've found searching Google, but it didn't solve my problem.

btw

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get autoclean
sudo apt-get clean
sudo apt-get autoremove
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade
```

is not working. Can somebody please help me fix this issue?

Answer (score 3):

Open up `top`, press `V` to enable tree view, and find the leaf process under `xenial -> xenial -> sh -> dpkg-preconfigre -> ... -> blocking leaf process`. Then kill (softly) this process:

```
sudo kill -s SIGTERM {process_id}
```

In my case, it was `grep` waiting for something that clearly wasn't coming.

Comment: This worked on my server too, however I'm curious whether this has any side affect. In my case it was `grep` too. May/Should I check for anything after upgrade completed?

Answer (score 2):

I noticed that a mysql process was starting every time I tried to upgrade and it was eating all of one of my processors. That same process stopped after I stopped the upgrade process. I was unable to determine the cause of that mysql process being stuck so I followed the advice from here: ["Failed to spawn mysql main process: unable to execute: No such file or directory"](https://askubuntu.com/questions/125686/mysql-fails-to-start-after-upgrade-to-12-04).

Then, after running apt-get upgrade it worked without a problem.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

1. Cleaning using two ways command.
   sudo apt-get clean && sudo apt-get update
2. dpkg --configure -a
3. apt-get install -f
   The last command will help you to remove all broken package.
4. sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade
5. reboot pc
6. Install the rest of the package through update-manager.

hope it helps