# How can I stop apache2 form starting at startup without removing it?

Tags: 11.10

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [how to stop apache2, mysql from starting automatically as computer starts?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/40072/how-to-stop-apache2-mysql-from-starting-automatically-as-computer-starts)

I dont want to remove apache2 as I it is the dependency of Debian Document Browser. How can I stop it from starting at startup ?